# How to find the quotient of two integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^\infty x^{1/2}e^{-x^3}\,dx=I$$
$$J=\int_0^1x^{-2/3}(1-x)^{-1/3}\,dx$$
$$J/I=?$$
I am confused how to find the value of $I$ and $J$. I tried to find them separately but couldn't.

I think by using some substitution in $J$ I shall get some scalar multiple of $I$, hence obtaining the required value.

I am stuck. Guide me!

Comment: Are you familiar with the Gamma and Beta functions?

Comment: No I M not. Can't it be solved without using that?

Comment: Technically, you can solve it without those functions, but why would you want to?

Comment: I don't understand these type of exercises. The two integrals have nothing to do with each other, it seems. Anyways, you have a way of calculating the first one in one answer, the second one looks easier.

Comment: @mickep: both integrals are related with the values of the $\Gamma$ function at $\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}$, and I do not agree about the second integral being "easier" than the first one!

Comment: Well, the second one has an elementary primitive...

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The second integral can be transformed into an integral of a rational function, making it elementary. That's one definition of "easier". :)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio See my hint below...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint for solving the second integral without beta function machinery:

$$\begin{align}
J
&=\int_{0}^{1}x^{-2/3}\left(1-x\right)^{-1/3}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt[3]{x^{2}\left(1-x\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^{2/3}\left(1+u\right)};~~~\small{\left[x=\frac{u}{1+u}\right]}\\
&=3\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^{3}};~~~\small{\left[\sqrt[3]{u}=t\right]}.\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: (+1) This is more or less what I meant. It is easier, since one can give it to a first-year calculus student.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. By the change of variable $t=x^3$, $dx=\frac13t^{-2/3}dt$, one gets
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{1/2}e^{-x^3}dx=\frac13\int_0^\infty t^{1/2-1}e^{-t}dt=\frac23\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}du
$$ then one may conclude with the [Euler gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) or with the [gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Concerning $J$ use the [Euler beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) result.